# eBay Trading API: Pass elements with same name via SOAP

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

I need to pass multiple `NameValueLists` via SOAP, but I have no idea how to include their data.

This is how it should look like:

```
<Variations>
      <VariationSpecificsSet>
        <NameValueList>
          <Name>Size</Name>
          <Value>XL</Value>
        </NameValueList>
        <NameValueList>
          <Name>Color</Name>
          <Value>Black</Value>
        </NameValueList>
    </VariationSpecificsSet>
</Variations>
```

Part of my PHP code:

```
$params->Item->Variations = new ArrayObject();
$params->Item->Variations->VariationSpecificsSet = new ArrayObject();
$params->Item->Variations->VariationSpecificsSet->NameValueList = new ArrayObject();

$list = new ArrayObject();
$list->name = 'title';
$list->value = "value";
$arr[0] = $list;
$arr[1] = $list;

$params->Item->Variations->VariationSpecificsSet->NameValueList = $arr;
$ebay->ebayCall( "VerifyAddFixedPriceItem", $params );
```

Debug output of `$params`:

```
[Variations] => ArrayObject Object
    (
        [VariationSpecificsSet] => ArrayObject Object
            (
                [NameValueList] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ArrayObject Object
                            (
                                [name] => title
                                [value] => value
                                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => ArrayObject Object
                            (
                                [name] => title
                                [value] => value
                                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => ArrayObject Object
                            (
                                [name] => title
                                [value] => value
                                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

The resulting request: No names, neither values in the `NameValueLists`

```
<ns1:Variations>
    <ns1:VariationSpecificsSet>
        <ns1:NameValueList/>
        <ns1:NameValueList/>
        <ns1:NameValueList/>
    </ns1:VariationSpecificsSet>
</ns1:Variations>
```

How do I put the data correctly in the `NameValueLists`? The debug output seems good to me, but it wont show up in the XML. I can't be the first one..?

**Edit**: I found a question on SO that describes exactly my problem:
[Php soap client multiple node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738556/php-soap-client-multiple-node)
I tried this approach before asking here, but it still dont work for me. I'm guessing, it has something to do with the eBay wsdl, but I cant figure out what exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing capital Letters at `$list->name` and `$list->value` is the answer. hope that helps anyone else sometime. grrr